# transfer cryptocurrency with api

Tags: api, currencies

I need a wallet that have api for currency transfer like block.io api. But because block.io only supports 3 currencies, it is not suitable for my project
There is another wallet for my work? (Only transfer currency with api And support for more currencies)

Comment: Blockchian.com supports more than 20 currencies. Have you checked it? https://www.blockchain.com/ticker

Comment: @YuyaOgawa Yes, but due to sanctions, Iranian users are blocked